# Working on 32 bits or 64 bits with raspberry

Tags: 64-bit

I am working with a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2 since several years.
I have installed several versions of Raspbian OS (from Noobs).
This OS seems to be the "official" Linux Raspberry distribution.

There is something i do not understand:

- My OS is working on 32 bits mode
- I have read this raspberry has a 64 bits CPU.

So i understand, everyone which buys a raspberry and install the "official" raspbian works with 64 bits hardware and 32 bits software.

This is no optimal ? We waste the advantage of 64 bits...
Why raspbian is not 64 bits whereas hardware supports 64 bits ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi started as a 32 bit computer. The Raspberry Pi foundation cares *a lot* about **backwards compatibility**. Maintaining or even creating **both** a 64-bit and 32-bit OS was seen as expensive with little benefit (the Raspberry Pi had less than 4 GB RAM for the longest time).

**The times have changed** : An official 64-bit version of the OS is [currently being beta tested.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=117&t=275370)

Comment: There is a more recent version of the beta here: https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_arm64/images/raspios_arm64-2020-08-24/